# Ошибка линковки через pragma

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

Использую 2 библиотеки в своем проекте: libyara и yaracpp.
Пытаюсь подключить через pragma:

```
#pragma comment ("lib", "yaracpp_x86_sd")
#pragma comment ("lib", "libyara_x86_sd")
```

Получаю ошибки линковки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробую вот так:

```
#pragma comment ("lib", "yaracpp_x86_sd.lib")
#pragma comment ("lib", "libyara_x86_sd.lib")
```

Поведение такое-же.

Однако, если подключить эти библиотеки через настройки линковщика:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То сборка происходит успешно. Правда с рядом предупреждений:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ScanService, Configuration: Debug         Win32 ------
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of 
other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__dclass' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(nan.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(value.obj)' in function '_json_real'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__errno' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(errno.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(load.obj)' in function '_json_load_file'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '__errno' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(errno.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(strconv.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '___acrt_iob_func' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(_file.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(load.obj)' in function '_json_loadf'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_fclose' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(fclose.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(load.obj)' in function '_json_load_file'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_fgetc' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(fgetc.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(load.obj)' in function '_json_loadf'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_fopen' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(fopen.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(load.obj)' in function '_json_load_file'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '___stdio_common_vsprintf' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(output.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(load.obj)' in function '_error_set'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '___stdio_common_vsprintf' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(output.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(error.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '___stdio_common_vsprintf' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(output.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(strconv.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_strtoll' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(strtox.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(load.obj)' in function '_lex_scan_number'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_strerror' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(strerror.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(load.obj)' in function '_json_load_file'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '__time64' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(time.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(hashtable_seed.obj)' in function '_generate_seed'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_strncpy' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(strncpy.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(hashtable.obj)' in function '_hashtable_set'
1>LINK : warning LNK4286: symbol '_strncpy' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(strncpy.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(error.obj)'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_strtod' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(strtod.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(strconv.obj)' in function '_jsonp_strtod'
1>LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_localeconv' defined in 'libucrtd.lib(localeconv.obj)' is imported by 'libyara_x86_sd.lib(strconv.obj)' in function '_jsonp_dtostr'
```

Папка с библиотеками подключена, и они в ней:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настраивать линковку в настройках Visual Studio не вариант, так как в зависимости от конфигурации и платформы для сборки линкуются разные версии библиотек, которые разворачиваются в макросах в pragma, что очень удобно, и настраивать отдельный файл для каждой конфигурации каждого проекта неразумно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почему о вас `"lib"` вдруг взято в кавычки вот здесь

```
#pragma comment ("lib", "yaracpp_x86_sd")
#pragma comment ("lib", "libyara_x86_sd")
```

?

Подключение библиотек через `#pragma comment` делается через

```
#pragma comment(lib, ...)
```